# Intrarater reliability

Tags: reliability, intraclass-correlation

I would like to estimate the intrarater reliability in a MRI study. Different regions of interest were manually traced with a mouse-driven cursor in order to estimate their volumes. All data were traced by the same rater and a subset of the data was traced twice. How can I estimate the intra-raterreliability of the brain volumes? Specifically, which type of intraclass correlation coefficient would you suggest?

Comment: Do you mean inter-rater reliability, or are you asking whether the rater was consistent within themself based on having done the tracing more than once?

Comment: I would like to estimate the intra-rater-reliability, because all tracings were done by the same person.